# best practice for Spring validation of AJAX JSON data

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm using AJAX to send JSON data from web page to back end, and need some validation strategies. I noticed that there're several ways to validate form parameters like SimpleFormController with ValidationUtils class and similar command object binding methods. But is there any suggestion to validate JSON data?

Thanks for even

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the whole controller hierarchy. It is obsolete. Use the new restful style in spring mvc (available in 2.5, improved in 3.0).

There, you can define:

```
@RequestMapping("/url/foo")
public String handleFooInput(@Valid YourObject obj) { .. }
```

This will bind the input JSON to the object you specify, and will validate it (if it is annotated with `javax.validation` annotations). Three preconditions to that:

- have jackson and jackson-mapper on your classpath, so that an object is created based on the JSON input
- have a `javax.validation` provider (hibernate-validator for example) on the classpath
- put `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm brand new to Spring and Hibernate. Can I use @Valid with Spring 2.5.6 and Hibernate 3.X and j2EE 5.0? Another quick question, do I need a class to load all parameters from UI JSON data?

Comment: you need an class; I don't think 2.5.6 supports @Valid