# Best way of server side validation in Spring MVC with Json data

Tags: json, validation, spring-mvc, jackson, bean-validation

Spring MVC + Jackson converting  Java object to/from Json data. I want to validate converted Java object. I should validate object using

1. Bean validation
2. In Controllers
3. Aspect
4. Is Spring dispatcher servlet supportvalidation phase like in FacesServlet

any others ... ?

What is the  best way of server side validation in Spring MVC .

Comment: possible duplicate of [best practice for Spring validation of AJAX JSON data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847284/best-practice-for-spring-validation-of-ajax-json-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No "best", only "most appropriate", which has many factors.

*I'd* rank my choices as bean validation first, controllers second, and wouldn't consider the rest.